# Solve a linear equation on every row in datatable

Tags: r

I did some linear regression and I want to forecast the moment of exceeding a certain value.

This means I have three columns:

```
a= slope
b = intercept
c = target value
```

On every row I want to calculate
    `solve(a,(c-b))`

How do I do this in an efficient way, without using a loop (it is an extensive dataset)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way using the `Vectorize` function:

```
solve_vec <- Vectorize(solve)
solve_vec(d$a, d$c - d$b)

> solve_vec(d$a, d$c - d$b)
[1] 12.0  6.0  4.0  3.0  2.4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, since I may use more difficult functionality later on. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to solve the equation

```
c = a*x + b
```

for `x` for each row? That has the pretty simple solution of

```
x = (c-b)/a
```

which is a vectorized operation in R. No loop necessary

```
dd <- data.frame(
   a = 1:5,
   b = -2:2,
   c = 10:14
)
transform(dd, solution=(c-b)/a)

#   a  b  c solution
# 1 1 -2 10     12.0
# 2 2 -1 11      6.0
# 3 3  0 12      4.0
# 4 4  1 13      3.0
# 5 5  2 14      2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the aforementioned responses, you could also use the `mutate` function from the `tidyverse`. like so:

```
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)

dataframe %<>% mutate(prediction=solve(a,(c-b))
```

in this example we are assuming the columns 'a','b', and 'c' are in a table called 'dataframe.' we then use the `%<>%` function from the `magrittr` library to say "apply the function that follows to the dataframe".